# Overloading operator on member enum of class template

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I'd like to make a template overload of `operator |` for an `enum` inside a class template.

Here is a minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
struct test1 {
    enum test2 {
        test3, test4
    };
};

template <class T>
typename test1<T>::test2 operator | (typename test1<T>::test2 f1, typename test1<T>::test2 f2) {
    return static_cast<typename test1<T>::test2>(
        static_cast<unsigned>(f1) | static_cast<unsigned>(f2)
    );
}

int main() {
    test1<int>::test2 flags = test1<int>::test3 | test1<int>::test4; // error here
}
```

[Live example.](http://ideone.com/0JeGtY)

Compiler shows the following diagnostic in this code:

```
In function 'int main()':
error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'test1<int>::test2' [-fpermissive]
  test1<int>::test2 flags = test1<int>::test3 | test1<int>::test4;
```

I also tried compiling this code with LLVM 6.1.0.

What is the problem with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in `typename test1<T>::test2`, template parameter `T` is in a [non-deduced context](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts), so C++ can not deduce its template argument from the types of the function arguments.

You can see this by explicitly instantiating the function template:

```
test1<int>::test2 flags = operator | <int> (test1<int>::test3, test1<int>::test4);
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/DIMeFV)

Or by using a non-template friend function of the class template:

```
template <class T>
struct test1 {
    enum test2 {
        test3, test4
    };
    friend test2 operator | (test2 f1, test2 f2) {
        return static_cast<test2>(
            static_cast<unsigned>(f1) | static_cast<unsigned>(f2)
        );
    }
};

int main() {
    test1<int>::test2 flags = test1<int>::test3 | test1<int>::test4;
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/5EKbpB)

See also:

- [g++ compilation error of another thing that works in msvs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2180297/1639256)
- [Candidate template ignored because template argument could not be inferred](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12566228/1639256)